# Rest API not returning lookup field value

Tags: rest, lookup-column, sharepoint-rest-api, user

I want to get the **Approver(people field)** value from list item using REST API where **Country(lookup field)** equals to 'ABC' and **Cluster(lookup field)** is equals to 'XYZ'

I have written below REST API it does not returning any result.

```
siteurl/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Approvers')/items?$expand=Approver,Country,Cluster&$select=Approver/Id,Approver/Title,Country/Id,Country/Title,Cluster/Id,Cluster/Title&$filter=Country eq 'ABC'
```

**NOTE:** If i hit same url without filter then i get result But it only showing Approver details not country and cluster field details.

Please help. Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a lookup field to a list in SharePoint, you can't filter by the name of the item in the lookup column. You will have to filter it using ID.

Refer below URL. This will work for you:

```
siteurl/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Approvers')/items?$expand=Approver,Country,Cluster&$select=Approver/Id,Approver/Title,Country/Id,Country/Title,Cluster/Id,Cluster/Title&$filter=CountryId eq 'ABC'
```

OR

```
siteurl/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Approvers')/items?$expand=Approver,Country,Cluster&$select=Approver/Id,Approver/Title,Country/Id,Country/Title,Cluster/Id,Cluster/Title&$filter=Country/Id eq 'ABC'
```